# Is it possible to pass the event and context as environment variables to an ecs container triggered by a cloud watch event

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ecs, amazon-cloudwatch

i want to pass trigger to an ecs instance when a file is uploaded to a bucket in s3 and process the uploaded file. so i need to get the bucket and file name into the ecs container. 
the ecs instance is not already running. but started when the event occurs

Answer (score 1):

> I want to pass trigger an ECS instance when a file is uploaded to a
>   bucket in s3 and process the uploaded file

First thing, Environment variable load at the boot time of application while the event is not known at the start of application.

So the best way to handle this is [SNS or SQS notification on s3 put event](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/fanout-s3-event-notifications-to-multiple-endpoints/). You need

- Put the file on S3
- Event notification sent to SNS (data enters S3, notification of new data is sent to SNS)
- SNS will trigger HTTP endpoint of your ECS container ( I assume that you already expose endpoint to process SNS topic.
- Get the Name of the object and S3 bucket Name from SNS topic.

You can also use SQS with SNS but HTTP endpoint seems good,A high-level architecture will look like

[image]

Or details diagram

[image: End to end diagram]

Comment: the ecs container will be started as a result of the file being uploaded to s3. i dont want to pass it to an already running container... or i might be misunderstanding what u mean

Comment: Okay fine so you need to pass events to lambda and lambda will create tasks definitions by passing bucket name and file name as a environment variables and the container will consumed, there is no out of the box feature of s3 that will start container but you can trigger lambda and then automate your rest of the process

Comment: you can check this link to start ecs task from lambda https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/better-together-amazon-ecs-and-aws-lambda/

Comment: Yeah i ended up using a lambda to set the env but i saw this [article](https://medium.com/@bowbaq/trigger-an-ecs-job-when-an-s3-upload-completes-3559c44c37d1) and started to think there might be a better way but i didnt want to use terraform

Comment: terraform is infrastructure as code tool, that will create resources for you, lambda is the only option that listen s3 event and will lauch container for you. you can create cluster wtih terraform its fine but that will be the lamda that will listen event

Comment: The problem with this approch is "There’s one problem though … the container has no idea which object in the bucket triggered the job." see the article it will not work in your case, but you will need Input Transformer which will then work

Comment: yeah ive pretty much given up on trying that :| ... i couldnt find a way to add the input transformer to the ecs target